# Local extrema for trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Determine the local extreme values of $$f(x)=\frac{x}{2}+\sin(x)$$

How do we determine the local extrema for trigonometric functions? Computing the derivative results in

$$f'(x)= \frac12 +\cos(x)$$

and from here

$$\frac12+\cos(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \cos(x)=  -\frac12 \Leftrightarrow x=\frac{2\pi}{3}+2\pi n \text{ or } x=\frac{4\pi}{3}+2\pi n.$$

But I'm not sure how should we continue from this point?

Comment: Evaluate $f(x)$.

Comment: You should also verify that $f''(x)>0$ (local minimum) or $f''(x)<0$ (local maximum) at these critical points, otherwise they need not be where local extrema occur

Comment: You should have $\frac12+\cos x=0\iff \cos x=-\frac12$.

Comment: Also note that $\cos x=-\frac 12$. You dropped the minus sign. And you should have two solutions in any $2\pi$ interval

Comment: Thanks for the note! Updated.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Could you elaborate bit, evaluating the exteme points? $f(\frac{2\pi}{3}+2\pi n)$ and $f(\frac{4\pi}{3}+2\pi n)$?

Comment: That's it, you are done.

Comment: @MPW Can i only evaluate $f''(\frac{2\pi}{3}) < 0$ and $f''({4\pi}{3}) > 0$ and conclude from here that the former is the maxima and latter the minima or should i also use the $2\pi n$?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Do i have to evaluate the $2\pi n$ also?

Comment: What does $x$ represent ?

Comment: Well in this case we can think of $x$ as the point on the unit circle and $2\pi n$ represents just $n$ cycles?

Answer (score 1):

$x$ lies in second and third quadrants.

$$\cos x =-\frac12\rightarrow  \pi+ 2 k\pi \pm \pi/3$$